# Dynamic HTML Rows from Array

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

If have an array like this

```
companies = [COMPANY_1, COMPANY_2]
```

I have an HTML file with a div class called 'companies'. How do I build rows in an HTML file so it displays the same as this (but dynamically)?

```
<div class="companies">
       <div class="row">
          <div id='company_1'>
           COMPANY_1
          </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="row">
          <div id='company_2'>
            COMPANY_2
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

This is within a Google Apps script and the array will always be changing. The HTML is for a sidebar in the Google Apps Script.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 3):

You may create element using javascript like

```
function CreateElementFromArray() {
   var companies = [COMPANY_1, COMPANY_2];
   var companyElement = document.getElementsByClassName('companies')[0];
   for (var i=0; i < companies.length; i++) {
     var nwtag = createElementHtml(companies[i], 'div', companies[i]);
     companyElement.appendChild(nwtag);
   }
}

    function createElementHtml(id,tagname, text) {
      var containerdiv = document.createElement('div');
      containerdiv.className = 'row';

      var nwtag = document.createElement(tagname);
      nwtag.id = id;
      containerdiv.innerText = text;
      containerdiv.appendChild(nwtag);
      return containerdiv;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by using innerhtml

```
var companies = ["COMPANY_1", "COMPANY_2"]

companies.forEach(company => {

document.getElementById("companies").innerHTML = document.getElementById("companies").innerHTML + `<div class="row">${company}<div>`
})
```